# Can I use CCTV cam as a usb web cam direct on PC?

Tags: usb, video, webcam, camera

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have unused CCTV camera, so I wanted to use it instead my web cam because it's quality is better,
I connected it with 12v adapter to power source and I convert an old USB cable to it's other port to give it 5 volts from the computer that will run on it, I test the port by the Multimeter the 5v okay from USB cable to the port and the power on.
But when I connects it Cheese program says "No device detected" but it's okay the program can detect the normal webcam.
So the question what's else I need to run it direct on computer?

[image: Cam and cables]
[image: Power on]

Comment: You of course have a Ubuntu driver for this device?

Comment: When I connected It I used apt update , apt upgrade, also checked the software and update -> additional drivers , but I couldn't find any drivers with that way.

Comment: There is your answer no driver it wont work.

Comment: So which driver I need to install so it can run?

Comment: Only the maker of the camera can tell you what if any driver there may be that you can use. I doubt there is any generic driver for such a thing.

Comment: Okay thank you :)

Comment: To get more information, watch `sudo journalctl  -f` as you connect the camera.

Comment: result
Apr 07 18:29:08 mrbassem sudo[2879]: mr-bassem : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/mr-bassem ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -f
Apr 07 18:29:08 mrbassem sudo[2879]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 07 18:29:41 mrbassem kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (4964 > 4963), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 40250
Apr 07 18:35:30 mrbassem kernel: [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=82721 end=82722) time 9065 us, min 763, max 767, scanline start 368, end 805